# GMail AddOn CardHeader.setImageUrl with url requiring authorization

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, urlfetch, gmail-addons

My Gmail add-on uses OAuth for a service (similar to the [github example](https://github.com/googlesamples/gmail-add-ons-samples)). Unlike the GitHub example where the avatar is a non-authenticated URL, the avatars in my add-on require authorization. Since my app is already successfully authorized, I was hoping Google would use that token when loading the image set via `CardHeader.setImageUrl`.

Is there a way to load and display an image that requires authorization?

What I tried:
- load the image via `UrlFetchApp`, but then there is no option to display the image using the CardHeader API.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with:

```
var headers = {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: 'get',
  headers: headers
});
var imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(response.getContent());

// Then creating the CardHeader using the image url
return CardService.newCardHeader()
  .setTitle('My Profile')
  .setImageUrl(imageUrl)
  .build();
```